# Website with address 'www' is not working in AWS EC2 Box

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webserver

I have a .net Box instance setup in AWS EC2.

I have over 25 sites there but one particular site in .net that doesn't work when `www.` is not added to it. What can I do to fix that?

In Chrome, for example, it says webpage is not available.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to troubleshoot at all?  Is DNS resolving?  Are your virtual hosts configured correctly?  What HTTP response do you get? Also this might best be suited for ServerFault

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your response. Basically I am new to AWS setup and I have no idea why is this happening. I'll be grateful if I can have some clue. Best.

Comment: Again there is nothing that can be done but speculate based on what you have posted.  You need to tell us the specific behavior you are seeing that is problematic.  What actually happens when you make a request against the www domain name?

Comment: Thanks Mike, it (for example in chrome) says webpage not visible. I updated the question. Is there any thing I could let you know? I hope I understood your question properly.

Comment: OK. But WHY is it not available?  There are any number of reasons that could happen.  You couyld have DNS configured improperly in which case the request never reaches the server.  You could have your host configured improperly, in which case your application may not recognize it needs to handle requests for that subdomain.  Or you could have an actual problem in your application.